# Issue using Messages in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am very new Django and the web development space in general. On my template, I have all of my database entries listed, and a search bar that queries the database and returns any results. I need help displaying a message when there are no results. Currently, when there are no results, the page simply reloads. I have tried implementing the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/), but I just can't get it to work (seems like I have to have it directed to another page). In the views.py, I have an if statement that is deciding what to do when there are no results, I just don't know how to produce a statement that appears on the same page as the query. I've tried extending templates, and putting variables in views.py, but they stay the page permanently. I've also considered Javascript, but I have yet to learn that. I prefer not use Haystack or DjangoSearch, as I think this is pretty simple to do. Please let me know if you require any other information. Thanks so much for any help!

My views.py

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpRequest
from django.contrib import messages
from vendor_db.models import Itemo
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, render_to_response, render, redirect, get_object_or_404

def vendors(request):
    items = Itemo.objects.all()
    var_2 = request.GET.get("q")
    if var_2:
        items = items.filter(Vendor_Name__icontains=var_2)
    if not items:
        messages.info(request, "No Results Found")
        return none
        people
    else:
        items
    context = {
        'items': items,
    }
    return render(request, 'vendor_db/vendors.html', context,())

def vendors_detail(request, id):

    try:
        item = Itemo.objects.get(id=id)
    except Itemo.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('This item does not exist')
    return render(request, 'vendor_db/vendors_detail.html', {
        'item': item,
    })
```

My vendors template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    {% load static %}
            <h2>All Vendors</h2>
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <form method='GET' action=''>
                <input type='text' name="q" placeholder='Search Vendors'/>
                <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
            </form>
            <form action="{% url 'vendors' %}"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Reset">
            </form>

    {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                {{ message }}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

            <h3>Sort by:</h3>
                <a href="{% url 'product_name_asc' %}">Product Name</a>
            <ul>
                {% for stuff in items %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'vendors_detail' stuff.id %}">
                        {{ stuff.Product_Name|capfirst }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from vendor_db import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^vendors/$', views.vendors, name='vendors'),
    url(r'^vendors/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.vendors_detail, name='vendors_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do this:

```
def vendors(request):
    items = Itemo.objects.all()
    var_2 = request.GET.get("q")
    if var_2:
        items = items.filter(Vendor_Name__icontains=var_2)

    return render(request, 'vendor_db/vendors.html', {'items': items})
```

and in the template you can do.

```
{% if items %}
... item output ...
{% else %}
No Results Found
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! This worked for me. I left the "...item output..." blank because my database is already showing the entries. But this is exactly what I needed. Kudos!!

Comment: No problem. Remember to try to keep things simple. Django and python try to make it really easy, so less is more.

Comment: Also, the idea of... Item output... In my example is for you to take your template code that outputs the items (if exists) otherwise you can just change my if statement to if not items. And remove the else.

Comment: You are absolutely right again! I instead put my loop of objects within the if statement, which makes so much more that way. I will try not to overcomplicate things in the future *thumbs up*.